# django: cannot create objects (models sqlite3) from other .py

Tags: python, xml, django, sqlite, sax

I use Django. I've created a project and an app.

views.py

```
..
import xmlparser
from models import Actividad
..
def All(request):
    xmlparser.MyHandler.procesar
    return HttpResponse("test")
```

xmlparser, xml sax parser, it works and prints content working out of django

```
from models import Actividad
..
class MyHandler

def characters (self, content):
    A = Actividad.objects.create(titulo = "..", tipo = "..")

def procesar (self):
    parser = xml.sax.make_parser()
    parser.setFeature(xml.sax.handler.feature_namespaces, 0)

    Handler = MyHandler()
    parser.setContentHandler(Handler)
    parser.parse('your.xml')
```

A has not been added when I go to "All" url. If I try, with the same line, to add info to the db from views.py, it works.

Answer (score 0):

This line :

```
xmlparser.MyHandler.procesar
```

doesn't actually *call* your method. It needs the parens:

```
xmlparser.MyHandler.procesar()
```